# PIVOT nested array in BigQuery without join key

Tags: sql, arrays, google-bigquery, pivot

I'm seeing some similar questions but couldn't find an answer that can fit my issue. I think that what I'm struggling with is the fact the array I want to unnest don't have any join keys (or maybe I don't understand the issue I'm facing).

So I have this dataset:

```
with raw as (
      select 
        ['a','b','c','d'] as keys,
        [1,2,3,4] values 
      union all 
      select 
        ['a','b','c','d']  ,
        [5,6,7,8]
    )

    select
      *
    from
      raw
```

I want to have a column for each keys and their corresponding values as rows.

So far I have something like this but I'm kind of stuck. I think I need to use offset at some point but I'm not sure how and where...

```
with raw as (
      select 
        ['a','b','c','d'] as keys,
        [1,2,3,4] values 
      union all 
      select 
        ['a','b','c','d']  ,
        [5,6,7,8]
    )
    
    select
      *
    from (
      select
        *
      from raw,
      unnest(keys) as un_keys,
      unnest(values) as un_values
    )
    pivot(max(un_values) for un_keys in ('a','b'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below should help

```
WITH raw AS (
  SELECT ['a','b','c','d'] AS keys, [1,2,3,4] VALUES UNION ALL 
  SELECT ['a','b','c','d'], [5,6,7,8]
)
SELECT * EXCEPT(line) FROM (
SELECT line, key, VALUE FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS line FROM raw 
), UNNEST(keys) AS key WITH OFFSET
JOIN UNNEST(VALUES) AS VALUE WITH OFFSET
USING (OFFSET))
PIVOT(ANY_VALUE(VALUE) FOR key IN ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'))
```

with output

[image]